# Save full URL path in menu on Twig template engine

Tags: php, symfony, twig

> /macros/subdepartments.html

```
{% macro displayChildren(departments, parent_id, deep, prefix) %}
    {% import _self as macros %}
    {% for dept in departments %}
        {% if dept.parent_id == parent_id %}
            {% set href = dept.seo_title ~ '/' ~ prefix %}
            <li><a href="/{{ href }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black" style="margin-left: {{ deep * 10 }}px;">{{ dept.title }}</a></li>
            {{ macros.displayChildren(departments, dept.id, deep + 1, href) }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

> common.html

```
<div class="departments">       
                <ul class="nav">
                    <div class="clearfix">                              
                        {% import '/macros/subdepartments.html' as macros %}    
                        {% for dept in common.departments %}
                            {% if dept.parent_id == 0 %}
                                <li><a href="/{{ dept.seo_title }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black">{{ dept.title }}</a><div class="dropdown-menu"><ol class="nav">{{ macros.displayChildren(common.departments, dept.id, 0, dept.seo_title) }}</ol></div></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>                  
                </ul>
            </div>
```

> department.html (extended from common.html by Twig)

```
<ol class="nav" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        {% for dept in common.departments %}
            {% if dept.id == selected_dept.parent_id %}
                <li><a href="/{{ dept.seo_title }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black">← {{ dept.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if dept.parent_id != 0 or dept.id == selected_dept.id %}
                {% if dept.parent_id == selected_dept.parent_id %}
                    <li><a href="/{{ dept.seo_title }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black{% if dept.id == selected_dept.id %} selected{% endif %}">{{ dept.title }}</a></li>
                    {{ macros.displayChildren(common.departments, dept.id, 1) }}    
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}</ol>
```

> common.departments array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [parent_id] => 0 [title] => Моторные масла [seo_title] => motor-oils [full_title] => [display] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [parent_id] => 0 [title] => Трансмиссионные масла [seo_title] => transmission-oils [full_title] => [display] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [parent_id] => 0 [title] => Присадки [seo_title] => additives [full_title] => [display] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [parent_id] => 0 [title] => Автокосметика [seo_title] => autocosmetics [full_title] => [display] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [parent_id] => 0 [title] => Сервисные продукты [seo_title] => service-products [full_title] => [display] => 1 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6 [parent_id] => 0 [title] => Технологические жидкости [seo_title] => process-fluids [full_title] => [display] => 1 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 7 [parent_id] => 0 [title] => Зимняя программа [seo_title] => winter-program [full_title] => [display] => 1 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 8 [parent_id] => 1 [title] => Синтетические [seo_title] => synthetic [full_title] => Синтетические моторные масла [display] => 1 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 9 [parent_id] => 1 [title] => Полусинтетические [seo_title] => semisynthetic [full_title] => Полусинтетические моторные масла [display] => 1 ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 10 [parent_id] => 1 [title] => Минеральные [seo_title] => mineral [full_title] => Минеральные моторные масла [display] => 1 ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 11 [parent_id] => 2 [title] => для МКПП (механика) [seo_title] => mt [full_title] => Трансмиссионные масла для МКПП [display] => 1 ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 12 [parent_id] => 2 [title] => для АКПП (автомат) [seo_title] => at [full_title] => Трансмиссионные масла для АКПП [display] => 1 ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 13 [parent_id] => 12 [title] => Test [seo_title] => test [full_title] => Test [display] => 1 ) )
```

In common.html all ok. In deparment.html I need to get the same href in {{ dept.seo_title }}. If I go to /at/transmission-oils/13/dept from common.html in the department.html I see wrong urls to the departments.

```
← Трансмиссионные масла (href: /transmission-oils/2/dept right!)
для МКПП (механика) (href: mt/11/dept wrong!, need to be /mt/transmission-oils/11/dept)
для АКПП (автомат) (href: at/12/dept wrong!, need to be /at/transmission-oils/12/dept)
Test (href: /test//13/dept wrong!, need to be /test/at/transmission-oils/13/dept)
```

So, how can I change the code in department.html to print full path to subdepartment? Maybe recursive function will get the all parent departments.

Comment: Can you please print_r `common.departments` so we get the context?

Comment: Thanks. And where do you want to save the full link?

Comment: I want to show the full link in the href of <a> tag. Is it possible to calculate this full link?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really understand. The context you given does not contain anything to generate such link.

Comment: I updated the structure. And change the word from can to should. The output should be such as in block. I need the URL tree on every levels of subdepartments. From parent to child(parent0-child1-childofchild1 etc.) Because in the subdepartments pages script shows only first parent and childs, I can't get all parents

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. I'll have a look within a couple of hours, I've also my work to finish :-).

Comment: I also added output in common file (works fine, with full seo_title)

Comment: @Alain Tiemblo please, look at my comment in the answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you misses the parent path in your hrefs.

I think there is an issue when you tell:

```
Subdept1_2_1 (link: subdept1_2_1-subdept1_2-subdept1-dept1)
```

Don't you mean tree in ascendent order, such as:

```
Subdept1_2_1 (link: dept1-subdept1-subdept1_2-subdept1_2_1)
```

Anyway, you can try with such code:

<kbd>main.twig</kbd>

```
{% import 'macros.twig' as macros %}    
{% for dept in departments %}
  {% if dept.parent_id == 0 %}
  <li><a href="/{{ dept.seo_title }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black">{{ dept.title }}</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <ol class="nav">{{ macros.displayChildren(departments, dept.id, 0, dept.title) }}</ol>
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

<kbd>macros.twig</kbd>

```
{% macro displayChildren(departments, parent_id, deep, prefix) %}
    {% for dept in departments %}
        {% if dept.parent_id == parent_id %}
            {% set href = prefix ~ '-' ~ dept.seo_title %}
            <li><a href="/{{ href }}/{{ dept.id }}/dept" class="black" style="margin-left: {{ deep * 10 }}px;">{{ dept.title }}</a></li>
            {{ _self.displayChildren(departments, dept.id, deep + 1, href) }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Note: to use the reverse path of your node, use:

```
{% set href = dept.seo_title ~ '-' ~ prefix %}
```

Instead of:

```
{% set href = prefix ~ '-' ~ dept.seo_title %}
```

Note: I changed file names for a better reproducibility.

Comment: i changed the file names too. the code in common.html(main.twig) works good. there are a problems in departmens.html with href(other things woorks fine too)

Comment: The given code gives you a full generation of the menu (with complete hrefs). I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Please, look at aliexpress.com. You will see the menu with dropdown-subcategories. When you go to any subcategory, you will see the subcategory map in the left block. Example: Electronics->Tablet. In the left side: Related Categories
<Computer & Office
Tablet PCs. In the categories menu I have full link to category, but if I go to subcategory(subdepartment), I can't get full seo_title, because the script displays only direct parent, not all parent. So, If I go to level 5 subcategory, the parent will subcategory 4, but I need another parent to complete the href

Comment: The tool works great if I see all categories (in header of the site), but not in left bar(in the categories page)

Comment: in the main.twig i've got great href on Subdept1_2_1 link - subdept1_2_1-subdept1_2-subdept1-dept1. But in the departments page on the same link i've got subdept1_2_1, without -subdept1_2-subdept1-dept1. Because in {{ dept.seo_title }} we have subdept1_2_1, without any parents

Comment: Sorry i dont understand. please give the code you're trying, the result you get and the result you're expecting. Your code looks very complex and I can't get further as this currently stands. Do not forget that we're trying to help for free, and we can't spend hours and hours on your specific problems if that doesnt worth it.

Comment: oh ok, I changed the question